# How to import a whole file as a single variable?

Tags: typescript

I have the following helper module which contains a couple of exported members (`helper.ts`):

```
import { pick } from 'lodash';

const KEYS = [
  'id', 'updatedAt',
];

/* Convert Enquiry model to get API response */
const toResponse = (enquiry: any) => {
  const pickedResponse = pick(enquiry.toJSON(), KEYS);

  return {
    ...pickedResponse,
    ...(pickedResponse.updatedAt && { updatedAt: pickedResponse.updatedAt.toISOString() }),
  };
};

module.exports = {
  toResponse,
  KEYS,
};
```

and I want to be able to import the whole file as a single variable which I can then use to access the module's members like so:

```
import helper from 'helper';

const transformEnquiry = (enquiry) => {
  const enquiryAsResponse = helper.toResponse(enquiry);
}
```

This is obviously incorrect syntax and I've tried it like this as well:

```
import * as helper from 'helper'
```

but I get the following error:
"Property 'toResponse' does not exist on type 'typeof import("helper.ts")'"

What is the correct way of importing the whole file as one object-like variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution:

in the original `helper.ts` file, changed `module.exports` to declaration exports:

```
export const KEYS = /* ... */

export const toResponse = /* ... */
```

and imported like so:

```
import * as helper from 'helper';
```